# How to setup Eclipse to run a login Junit test before each test for Android testing?

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

I have hundreds Android jUnit tests. When I  debug a test, it becomes very annoying as our Android app requires  login. I do have a test called AuthenticationTest to login which is always the first test case to run if I run the entire suite. After that test passes, it will leave the application with a user signed in and the rest tests can continue to run.

When I do debugging, I want to find a way to allow me to run AuthenticationTest first, and then run the test I want to debug only on Eclipse. I do not want to call the login method inside of each test case as it will make our testing not efficient when we run all tests on CI.

Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know of the @Before annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation `@Before`

Say that is your example test:

```
 public class Test{

    @Before public void initialize() {
       //do your login and authentication here or any setup
    }
    @Test public void testCase1() {
       //test case1
    }
    @Test public void testCase2() {
       test case2
    }
 }
```

Source: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html